# Testing file upload in Spring Boot leads to FileUploadException (multipart boundary was not set)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, file-upload, multipart

I'm trying to upload files to my Spring Boot application and directly writing them to their destination (not in a temp file first). The application code I have works, but I can't get my unit test to work. My controller looks like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleFileUpload(final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if (!isMultipart) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(BAD_REQUEST, "Input was not of type multipart");
        }

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        FileItemIterator fileIterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
        while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = fileIterator.next();
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                // Save the file
                try {
                    return myFileStorageService.store(item.openStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
        throw new ResponseStatusException(BAD_REQUEST, "Input did not contain a file");
    }
```

This code works great, but my test doesn't:

```
    @MockBean
    private MyFileStorageService myFileStorageService;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void shouldUploadFile() throws Exception {
        final InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("testfile.txt");
        final MockMultipartFile testFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "testfile.txt", null, inputStream);

        doReturn("success!").when(myFileStorageService).store(testFile);

        mockMvc.perform(multipart("/upload").file(testFile))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("success!"));

        verify(myFileStorageService).store(testFile);
    }
```

This results in the following exception:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.init(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.getMultiPartStream(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:252)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.getItemIterator(ServletFileUpload.java:134)
    at com.lolmewn.FileUploadController.handleFileUpload(FileUploadController.java:128)
...
```

And in my config, I have configured the following:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: false
      max-file-size: -1
      max-request-size: -1
```

I expect Spring would generate the multipart boundaries for me, just like the browser or Postman do, is this not the case? I saw many similar questions, with most of them explicitly setting their content-type as the primary error, but as far as I know I'm not setting a content-type anywhere, so I expect Spring to generate it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default application.properties, then add `@SpringBootTest` annotation at top of your class which will instantiate it. If using something like application-test.properties you need to include `@ActiveProfiles(test)`
as well.
If you are using a config class to represent it

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = YourConfig.class)
```

EDIT: Change

```
 final MockMultipartFile testFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "testfile.txt", null, inputStream);
```

To

```
final MockMultipartFile testFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "testfile.txt",  
MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, inputStream);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I've tried adding the `@SpringBootTest` annotation, but this resulted in none of my tests running anymore. For reference, the test class is currently annotated by `@WebMvcTest(controllers = FileUploadController.class)`. Is it your guess that the test isn't picking up the application settings? I don't see how my error and that would be related, however

Comment: Check the edit i missed that in the code

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that only changes the content type of the file I'm uploading, not of the request itself, and therefore doesn't work.